# Can a Pokemon that I tried to capture from field research run away?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've completed one field research that has Sableye as a reward and when I throw my first Pokeball, it ran away.

If I'm not mistaken I got Sableye as a reward after I used 7 charged super effective moves at gym battle.

I thought a Pokemon that we tried to capture from field research as a reward can't run away.

So, is it true that Pokemon from field research also can run away?

Comment: If it weren’t for the fact that the Pokémon did run away, it would be a duplicate of [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/331005/124566) question. But given the fact it did run away and the answer indicates it’s probably a bug, I think your question is fine

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe this is rather a visual glitch, meaning you actually caught the Pokemon and should find it by filtering to recently caught. Or you caught the Pokemon whilst travelling faster than the speed cap/during a soft ban. If it's the latter you should be able to encounter the Pokemon again once you've returned to a normal state.

Comment: I can agree on that it’s a visual glitch. I’ve experienced far too many times, especially when catching Meltans

Comment: Definitely a visual glitch, I had this happen with a shiny Pokemon in my research once. Luckily it showed as caught in my journal even though it looked like it ran away.